# How does Samsung Download Booster work?

Tags: http, download, streaming, range

I just found the feature "Download Booster" on my new Note 4. I searched the web and found on Samsungs Website that it only works with Servers supporting HTTP Range Requests and HTTP Streaming capabilty but **is it only for HTTP File Downloads or for video streaming etc., too?**
-> http://www.samsung.com/au/galaxys5/features.html

Many online news websites say that it is only for file downloads and explicitly not for video streams, others claim the contrary...

Furthermore I read that it works only with HTTP 1.1: 
-> http://www.samsung.com/levant/support/skp/tsg/636497#none

What does "HTTP Streaming capability" mean?
I think I understood Range Requests (is it usual to use Range Requests only for boring full file downloads or other use cases, too?), but not fully chunk mode. Does HTTP Streaming capability and the support of version 1.1 mean Download Booster works on chunked transfer encoding? 
If so, does this mean that the client requests a source and the server answers with many chunks, how can Samsung request then specific chunk on the mobile connection and others on Wifi?

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, no one answered so far...